# Action Not Found For request 'GET /' These routes have been tried, in this order: Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.6

Migrating from sbt 0.13.0 to 1.3.0,scala 2.10.3 to 2.12.3 and play Version from 2.2.6 to 2.6.6

Below is the description of my problem

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: conf/application.conf #6507

I got the above error so I understood that application.conf file is missing so added application.conf an empty file in conf directory in  project root directory . Actually my project has application.conf file under : project/modules/core/conf folder.

After adding a conf file under root directory I am getting the below error:

```
http://localhost:9000 - Action Not Found
For request 'GET /'
```

These routes have been tried, in this order:

In sbt console :

```
[warn] p.db.DBModule - Configuration not found for database: No configuration setting found for key 'db'
[info] p.a.h.EnabledFilters - Enabled Filters (see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters):

play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter
play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev) (no global state)
```

Comment: What does you `routes` files (in `conf` directory) looks like?

Comment: Also, have you checked out the different migration guides from 2.2 to 2.6? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Migration28 (contains a link to previous migration guides)

Comment: @GaëlJ I have followed the migration steps for play 2.6 according to my project requirements. The problem is while executing sbt run it is expecting application.conf and Routes.scala under project root directory but my project structure is multi-project and the files are present in : 

application.conf file under : project/modules/core/conf folder.
and Routes.scala file under : project/modules/core/app/polaris/Routes.scala

Answer (score 0):

Try starting sbt with the flags which point it to the correct application.conf.

Include the flag -Dconfig.resource="path/application.conf" when starting the project.

That should sort the DB errors if your config is correct...

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ConfigFile?

Comment: I will try to execute with this command. Thank You.

@GaëlJ I have followed the migration steps for play 2.6 according to my project requirements. The problem is while executing sbt run it is expecting application.conf and Routes.scala under project root directory but my project structure is multi-project and the files are present in : 

application.conf file under : project/modules/core/conf folder.
and Routes.scala file under : project/modules/core/app/polaris/Routes.scala

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

`play.filters.hosts.allowed += "."`

Comment: [font](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/host-not-allowed/6202)